# Joint Distribution of two iid Standard Gaussian variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I've recently been asked this during an interview and I'm very curious about how to solve questions like these because I tried looking it up with almost no results. Given $X$, $Y$ that are i.i.d. random variables with distributions $N(0,1)$, what are the distributions (mean and variance) of the following:

1. $ X+Y | Y = y $
2. $ X | X+Y=c$

Everywhere I looked seemed to give answers for the distributions of $X|Y$ or something of the like. What do I do with linear transformations of gaussian RV's?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

Comment: I looked that up, but the numbers don't seem to add up. Is it just: 1. $ N(E[y], Var(Y))=N(0,1)$ and 2. $N(0,1)$ as well? That doesn't make sense and doesn't add up to what I was told the answer was during the interview

Answer (score 1):

In the first problem,

> $X+Y=X+y\sim N(y,\,1)$.

The mean & variance are easy to prove; if it's not  obvious to you that the distributions are as claimed, prove it with e.g. MGFs.

Let $p$ denote the joint PDF of $X,\,Y$ in the second problem, so the marginal PDF of $X$ is$$\frac{p(X=x,\,Y=c-x)}{\int_{\Bbb R}p(X=x^\prime,\,Y=c-x^\prime)dx^\prime}=\frac{e^{-x^2+cx-c^2/2}}{\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x^{\prime2}+cx^\prime-c^2/2}dx^\prime}\propto e^{-(x-c/2)^2},$$i.e. $X\sim N(c/2,\,1/2)$.

Comment: Any links to resources that provide an explanation for how to calculate  and $\sigma^2$? I'm not even sure what to look up :/

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees We've done better than that: we've determined which Normal distributions apply in each problem. Of course, $N(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$ has mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Well I understand that we've determined that these are normal distributions with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, my question is if there are any resources where I can learn more regarding that, I'm trying to learn so that I never make the same mistake again